# php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in

Tags: php

i am new to php and i am doing some coding

```
<?php $url='Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/');' ?>
```

i am getting the following error when i used this code :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

i am not getting what is the error.

please help me to find solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely a php related question and not specific to magento

Comment: is there any stackoverflow group to post purely related to php questions?

Comment: you can use stackoverflow.com to ask any code related questions. Just put tag - php there. You can also put the tag -magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using single quotes in PHP code and they are not closed properly.

change

```
<?php $url='Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/');' ?>
```

to

```
<?php $url = Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes from function call

```
<?php $url='Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/');' ?>
```

To

```
<?php $url= Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/');?>
```